# how to update hour in java?

Tags: java, clock

I made ​​a clock in java that shows the current time. I would make sure that the clock both updated at intervals of one minute, thus updating the result in the console. 
I read to use threads, but I'm not very knowledgeable on the subject, who would help me to make it happen?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Current
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
      String hour;
      int time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
      int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      int sec = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

      if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
          hour = "A.M.";
      else
          hour = "P.M.";
      System.out.println(time + ":" + m + ":" + sec + " " + hour);
  }
  }

     class Data
     {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
     Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
     int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
     int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     System.out.println(day + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year);
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60*1000); //one minute

            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            String hour;
            int time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int sec = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
                hour = "A.M.";
            else
                hour = "P.M.";
            System.out.println(time + ":" + m + ":" + sec + " " + hour);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that is more easy to format the date.

Sample code

```
final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);//60 seconds interval
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Note: It might generate correct result but not accurate always.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are outdated on two counts:

- The old date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormate` are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.
- Java now offers a more sophisticated way to schedule a regular background task: The [Executor framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) such as the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). The [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class documentation suggests using this newer approach in its stead.

Here is an example, ready to run. Both the `ScheduledExecutorService` and the java.time classes are discussed in many other Questions. Search Stack Overflow for more discussion.

In a nutshell, the `ScheduledExecutorService` is responsible for running your desired task every so often. You may ask for every minute, but remember that it may not be *exactly* every minute on a conventional implementation of Java (you would need a [real-time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java) implementation to be precise). Here we have told our executor to use a pool of a single background thread to run our task of telling the time. The one trick here is that any Exception reaching the `ScheduledExecutorService` will cause the scheduling to cease, silently with no comment or warning. So be sure your task code is always nested in a try-catch as shown and commented in this example below.

For telling the time, we capture the current moment in a particular time zone. We then create a string to represent that moment. I suggest letting java.time automatically localize such strings, as shown in the commented-out code. But here, per the Question, we generate a string with an AM/PM time-of-day only format. Here is a shortened version of the code seen in the example further down.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ); // Desired/expected time zone. Always specify the zone; Never depend on the JVM’s current default as it can change at any moment.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneId );  // Capture the current moment for that time zone.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "hh:mm:ss a" , Locale.US );  // Format the time-of-day only.
String output = zdt.format ( formatter );  // Generate a String to represent this date-time value.
```

Example, ready to run:

```
package javatimestuff;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Basil Bourque
 */
public class TellTimeConsole {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        TellTimeConsole app = new TellTimeConsole ();
        app.doIt ();
    }

    private void doIt () {
        System.out.println ( "INFO - TellTimeConsole::doIt - Running." );
        BeeperControl bc = new BeeperControl ();
        bc.beepEveryMinute ();  // Ask that object to launch the background thread to tell time every minute.
        try {
            Thread.sleep ( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis ( 5 ) ); // Run for five minutes and then shutdown this main thread and the background thread too.
            bc.halt ();  // Ask that object to stop the background thread.
        } catch ( InterruptedException ex ) { // This main thread is either being woken-from-sleep or stopped.
            System.out.println ( "INFO - TellTimeConsole::doIt - main thread of TellTimeConsole app interrupted." );
            bc.halt ();  // Ask that object to stop the background thread.
        }
    }

    class BeeperControl {

        private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool ( 1 );
        private final ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
        private final Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
        //private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale ( this.locale );
        private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "hh:mm:ss a" , this.locale );

        public void beepEveryMinute () {
            // Define task to be performed.
            final Runnable beeper = new Runnable () {
                public void run () {
                    try {
                        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneId );
                        System.out.println ( "Now: " + zdt.format ( formatter ) );
                    } catch ( Exception e ) {
                        // Always surround your task code with a try-catch, as any uncaught exception causes the scheduler to cease silently.
                        System.out.println ( "Exception unexpectedly reached 'run' method. " + e.getLocalizedMessage () );
                    }
                }
            };
            // Start performing that task every so often.
            System.out.println ( "INFO - BeeperControl::beepEveryMinute - Scheduling the executor service to run now. Runs indefinitely." );
            final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate ( beeper , 0 , 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); // (Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
        }

        public void halt () {
            System.out.println ( "INFO - BeeperControl::halt - shutting down the ScheduledExecutorService." );
            scheduler.shutdown ();  // Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.
            // scheduler.shutdownNow(); // Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
        }
    }

}
```

See this code [run live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/lGBdt6). Can only run briefly there, then hits a time limit imposed by IdeOne.com.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).